# DataTemplate in Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a custom control (NavigationContentCtrl) for displaying various Views/ViewModels.

In the Resources of the custom control, the data template for a given ViewModel points to the corresponding View (for simplicity I have included only one VM/V pair):

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SampleMainContentViewModel}">
            <views:SampleMainContentView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

There is also a ContentPresenter bound to an underlying Dependency Property:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                  Content="{Binding CurrentContentViewModel,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

In the backing Dependency Property (CurrentContentViewModel), if I instantiate a VM in the property, then the control finds the corresponding View and displays it correctly.

For example, using "SampleMainContentViewModel", this works fine:

```
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentContentViewModel.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentContentViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentContentViewModel", typeof(object), 
            typeof(NavigationContentCtrl), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SampleMainContentViewModel(), 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

However, if I try to set the VM when I am using an instance of the custom control (e.g. in the MainWindow):

```
<Grid>
    <controls:NavigationContentCtrl
        CurrentContentViewModel="{x:Type vm:SampleMainContentViewModel}"
        />
</Grid>
```

Then all I get is the string name of the VM:

[image]

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Note that `{x:Type vm:SampleMainContentViewModel}` is only the view model type, not an instance of it. You should bind `CurrentContentViewModel` to a property of type SampleMainContentViewModel. Just out of curiosity, is there any particular reason that the CurrentContentViewModel binds two-way? That doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: @Clemens .  Of course.  What a silly error.  Long day.  You are similarly correct that BindsTwoWayByDefault is not required.  I was just scrabbling around.  I have simplified my Dependency Property and switched the binding of the ContentPresenter to the simpler TemplateBinding syntax.  All working fine now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Clemens for prompting my brain-reboot.

In the instantiation of the control (e.g. in the MainWindow), the control's dependency property should be bound to property:

```
<Grid>
    <controls:NavigationContentCtrl            
        CurrentContentViewModel="{Binding ContentViewModel}"
        />
</Grid>
```

The property, ContentViewModel, is declared and set in the underlying MainWindowViewModel:

```
public object ContentViewModel { get; set; } = new SampleMainContentViewModel();
```

Further, the Dependency property can be simplified to remove the BindsTwoWayByDefault syntax and the ContentPresenter's Content property can be set using the simpler TemplateBinding syntax.